# vba if iserror (xxx) = true then return reference cells causing the error

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

i have a script that looks at an entire row of cells and returns which cells have errors. works just fine. but I want to expand that a bit because those cells have formulas referencing other cells.

in excel VBA, is there a way to check a cell for an error (iserror(cell) = true, and the output is the cell that is referenced in the cell with the error.

example. 
cell "D3" has the error #N/A. In cell D3 is the formula =vlookup(concatenate(C1,D1),tableX,2,false)

In the code, I would want the output to read "cell error in D3, see cells C1 and D1 for error tracing"

searched the website and finding a lot of irrelevant information. any help is appreciated

Comment: Look into `Range.Dependents`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon wouldn't that be `Range.Precedents` or am I mistaken?

Comment: @BigBen correct.